# Does seq assignment create a new seq copy?

Tags: assign, seq, shallow-copy, nim-lang

Given tow seqs, a and b, declared like this:

```
var
  a = @[1, 2, 3]
  b = @[4, 5, 6]
```

will `a = b` create a new seq copying everything from b to a or, reuse a? I have problems specially regarding to shallowCopy. I cannot tell what are they doing different.

Comment: By using `repr` you can see that `a` points to a new address after the assignment, so it is a new copy. But you are right, I also see a new address when taking a `shallowCopy` in this example, And the new address is _not_ the address of `b`, which one might expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is mostly yes.

The long answer is that sequence assignment is handled by the procs, appearing in the [assign module](https://github.com/nim-lang/Nim/blob/devel/lib/system/assign.nim), which is part of the system module. You can search this file for `tySequence` to see the relevant code.